# Absolute value weird inequality Lesbegue integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have stumbled upon the following inequality on a proof that does not make sense to me. By the way the lambda stands for the Lesbegue measure on the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B},\lambda)$.

$\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}\int_\limits{a_j}^{b_j}|f|d\lambda\geqslant\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}|\int_\limits{a_j}^{b_j}f\:d\lambda|$

This seems contradictory to me.

Why is it instead $\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}\int_\limits{a_j}^{b_j}|f|d\lambda\leqslant\sum_\limits{j=1}^{n}|\int_\limits{a_j}^{b_j}f\:d\lambda|$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you mean "why *isn't* it instead...", right?

Comment: If you apply this to a step function, it turns into the triangle inequality (and this should also tell you how to prove it in general).

Comment: One might ask why you think the "instead" inequality would be true. For $f$ that is sometimes positive and sometimes negative, you propose to take the absolute value _after_ integrating over both the positive and negative values of $f$ (allowing some positive and negative values to "cancel" each other) and obtain a result as great as (or greater than) if you replace all the negative values with positive ones _before_ you integrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $n=1$, $a=-\pi,\ b=\pi$ and $f(x)=sin(x)$. Then $\int_a^b |f| > 0 = |\int_a^b f|$.

Comment: That's just one example.

Comment: It' rather a *counter-example* to the inequality that you expect to be true.

Comment: By "you" I guess you meant the OP. But yes, you're right, it shows the "instead" inequality is wrong.

Comment: Oops, sorry yes, I assumed you were the OP and didn't check the names.